# Creating a class instance that will lose 1hp every minute?

Tags: python, class

I want to create several "Players" instances that they will automatically lose hp after some time (e.g. 60 seconds).
Say I have a class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp=1000):
        self.hp = hp

    def lose_hp(self): #not sure if there's a better way to do this than to call this function every 60 seconds
        pass
```

Is there a way to do that without having to call the `lose_hp` function for each player? (if I have 10000 players it might be difficult).

Comment: Record the time when the instance is created and subtract it from the current time to calculate the remaining hp.

Comment: Do you want it to continue losing HP (say, 10 HP every 60 seconds) or make it lose HP once?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I need it to continue lose hp every some fixed number of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the base HP at object creation and the object creation time, and compute the actual HP based on the current time on the fly:

```
import time

class Player:
    HP_LOSS_INTERVAL = 60
    HP_LOSS_PER_INTERVAL = 10

    def __init__(self, hp=1000):
        self.base_hp = hp
        self.birth_time = time.time()

    def hp(self):
        hp_loss = (time.time() - self.birth_time) // HP_LOSS_INTERVAL * HP_LOSS_PER_INTERVAL
        return max(0, self.base_hp - hp_loss)
```

Here I did it with `time.time()`, probably in a game you want to use a timer based on your game loop ticks.

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain how this works? I get the `time.time() - self.birth_time` idea, but wouldn't I have to call `Player.hp()` every time for it to update the player's hp? Is it really automatic once I create the `Player` instance?

Comment: You don't _update_ the player HP - you invoke `hp` to know it, and it calculates the current HP based on the current time.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot

Comment: Of course if you have other stuff affecting HP (e.g. damage from other players) you have to decrement/increment `base_hp`. Also, if you for some reason need to restore full health you'll also have to reset `birth_time` besides `base_hp`.

Comment: Neat. And every time I suppose I just use `Player.hp` to calculate the change?

Comment: say you have `p = Player(100)`, then you have to call `p.hp()`. This can also be changed to a property to make it usable as `p.hp` (without function call parentheses), but IMO it's better to make it clear that it's a function call that calculates stuff.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: By the way, I just thought of something. Is there a way to automatically remove the class instance when the `hp` goes below `0`?

Comment: `hp` would work well as a property, letting you write `p.hp` instead of `p.hp()` to get its current hit points.

Comment: @Penguin That depends on what you mean by "remove". Assuming you mean "get rid of a reference", that isn't something an object can do: it has no control over who holds a reference to it.

Comment: @chepner I see. I suppose I'll just have to continuously check the hp and if it's below 0 call `del Player` or something?

Comment: It's unlikely you need to use `del` at all. Presumably, you have a list of players from which  you could remove the instance, or if there is only one player, the game simply ends.